# Order of precedence of mixed operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

What would be the order of precedence if different kind of operators are used in same expression without parantheses?

For example, consider the following example. Why it has to be from `left-to-right` instead of `right-to-left` having the facts such as `typeof` operator has `right-to-left` order of precedence and `+` has `left-to-right` precedence.

```
typeof 99 + 'foo' // 'numberfoo'
typeof (99 + 'foo') // 'string'
```

Why the output of `typeof 99 + 'foo'` has to be 'numberfoo' instead of 'string' ?

Any reference to the documentation would be helpful.

Comment: He first converts 99 to Number, then he adds a `foo`

Comment: It's not about associacivity but first you have to consider the operator precedence.

Comment: Simply because `typeof 99` produces `"number"` this string is then joined by 'foo'. On the second row, you force the interpreter to create a string by using `(` and `)` thats why is already a string before check it via `typeof `.

Comment: You can see the rule from the example, which is equivalent to `(typeof 99) + 'foo'`.

Comment: Parsing of expressions with mixed operators is decided by *precedence*, not associativity.

Comment: There's no mixing of *operators* here, you are asking about mixing *operands* of different types.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Most non-assignment expressions in JavaScript (as with many other languages and in mathematics) are evaluated from left to right, however the types of operators used in the expression can alter this default behavior.

**The key thing to understand in this example is that [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a JavaScript *operator*, not a *keyword*, so it has a place in the order of operations.**

In your first example: `typeof 99 + 'foo'`

The expression begins (left-to-right) with `typeof 99`. `typeof` is right-to-left associative, so the `99` goes to `typeof` and the result is `"number"`.

Then the evaluation continues on (from left-to-right) with `+ 'foo'`. `+` is left-to-right associative, so "number" and "foo" are concatenated to each other and `"numberfoo"` is outputted.

In your second example, you introduce the grouping operator `()`, which changes the normal order of operations and the expression inside the group is evaluated first. In that case you have a `number` and a `string`, with the `+` operator between them. Whenever you have the `+` operator and either one of its operands are a `string`, the other will automatically be converted to a `string`, so the result there is `typeof string`, which produces `string`.

Here are the general order of operations:

1. Parenthesis
2. Exponenents
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Addition (either string or numeric)
6. Subtraction

See **[the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)** for more including an associativity table showing which operators have what associativity.